# Regex to search through a file for a set of parentheses with eight characters inside them, all 1s or 0s, with at least one 1?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to search through a file for a set of parentheses with eight characters inside them, all 1s or 0s, with at least one 1.
I currently am using the regex below, enumerating all possible such parentheses sets, i.e. brute forcing it.
Is there a better way to do this?

My regex:

`(11111110)|(11111101)|(11111100)|(11111011)|(11111010)|(11111001)|(11111000)|`...`|(11111111)` etc.

Comment: Yeah, use `grep -oP '\b(?=[01]{8}\b)0*1[10]*'`

Comment: See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53288248/3832970), I modified my comment as I did not realize you wanted to match these binary data inside parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
grep -oP '\((?=[01]{8}\))0*1[10]*\)' file
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Gfe9Td/1).

**Details**

- `-o` - outputs matches rather than matching lines
- `P` - enables PCRE regex engine

**Pattern**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?=[01]{8}\))` - a positive lookahead that requires eight `0` or `1` chars up to to a `)`
- `0*` - 0+ zeros
- `1` - a `1` char
- `[10]*` - 0 or more zeros or ones
- `\)` - a `)`.

Comment: This works great too. Of course, as it is by Wiktor "The Great Regexer" :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex,

```
\((?=[10]{8})(?=.*1.*).{8}\)
```

**Explanation:**

- `\(` --> Matches a literal `(` (starting brace)
- `(?=[10]{8})` --> Look ahead ensuring next eight characters are composed of zero and one only
- `(?=.*1.*)` --> Look ahead ensuring the presence of at least one '1' character
- `.{8}` --> matches exactly eight characters
- `\)` --> Matches a literal `)` (closing brace)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lr8haq/1)

Comment: Thanks for your help, however that still finds the string (00000000) which I was hoping to avoid, as its the base case

Comment: It doesn't match (00000000). Check this https://regex101.com/r/lr8haq/2

Answer (score 0):

This regex could also work:

```
(?!\(00000000\))\(\d{8}\)
```

Comment: See [Lookarounds (Usually) Want to be Anchored](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#anchor).